# Node to telnet data transfer

Tags: node.js, telnet

I'm trying to control a router via Telnet from node, I have used the below set of code to connect and the connection worked fine but I'm not able to find a proper documentation to transfer JSON data from my node server to the routing device via telnet, Please can anyone help me with some documentation or samples to transfer data..

```
var net = require('net');
    
var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(22, 'test.rebex.net', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
 
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
    client.destroy(); 
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

Comment: `client.write(JSON.stringify(...))` ?! Or what is the problem?

Comment: I'm able to write the data but how to capture a success response from the router... @Marc

Comment: I want to know whether the data is transferred successfully or not to the router

Comment: The data event should fired when the router sends somehting back. Keep in mind, that you have perhaps to send `\r\n` or so, to tell the router you hit "enter", like in a "real" telnet connection.